# How to destroy a stateful session bean

Tags: jsf, ejb, ejb-3.1

I have a SFSB defined bellow:

```
@Named("loginManager")
@Stateful
@SessionScoped
public class LoginManager {
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;
```

And I have a `@Remove` annotated method:

```
@Remove
public void remove() {
    log.info("loginManager removed");
}
```

But when I call this method in `h:commandButton`, an Exception is thrown:

```
16:19:32,640 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-64) #{loginManager.logout()}: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsupportedOperationException: WELD-000037: Cannot call EJB remove method directly on non-dependent scoped bean public java.lang.String cn.fh.codeschool.action.LoginManager.logout(): javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginManager.logout()}: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsupportedOperationException: WELD-000037: Cannot call EJB remove method directly on non-dependent scoped bean public java.lang.String cn.fh.codeschool.action.LoginManager.logout()
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-3.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-3.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-3.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

[image]

How can I destroy SFSB by myself instead of by container? I find that when I request a SFSB, there will be many beans constructed instead of one. I really concern about the memory usage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

SFSB should not be used in this way. Normally I need to inject it to a managed bean then invoke SFSB's business logic inside that managed bean.

If we want to destroy SFSB by calling `@Remove` method, we shoud Remove the `@Named` and the `@SessionScoped` annotation on that SFSB.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation :

- **retainIfException:** If true, the stateful session bean will not be removed if an exception is  thrown from the designated method.
- At the end of the lifecycle, the client invokes a method annotated `@Remove`, and the EJB container calls the method annotated `@PreDestroy`, if any. The bean’s instance is then ready for garbage collection.

Therefore, in case of exception, the bean isn't removed by the container. You can call this method to make it eligible for garbage collection.

```
@Remove(retainIfException=false)
public void remove() {
    log.info("loginManager removed");
}
```

---

**Edit:** 
If the application calls the `remove()` on the instance of a session bean with scope other than `@Dependent` it would result in `UnsupportedOperationException`.

> Stateful session beans may define a remove method, annotated @Remove,
>   that is used by the application to indicate that an instance should be
>   destroyed. However, for a contextual instance of the bean—an instance
>   under the control of CDI—this method may only be called by the
>   application if the bean has scope @Dependent. For beans with other
>   scopes, the application must let the container destroy the bean.

Comment: But I still got that exception and JSF sent me to an error page

Comment: @Neo Refer edit part, there is issue with JSF scope. I am not much into it, try changing if it works.

Comment: I've figured it out. I should remove the `@Named` and `@SessionScoped` annotation.